# Usar .on() ao invés de .bind() no JsHelper do CakePHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp

Quando escrevo Ajax com JsHelper do CakePHP, se escrevo algo como isso

```
$this->Js->get('#searchCity')->event(
        'click', $this->Js->request(
                'http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON', array(
            'async' => true,
            'dataExpression' => true,
            'method' => 'GET',
            'data' => "{}",
            'dataType' => 'JSON',
            'success' => ""
                )
        )
);
```

a saída é mais ou menos assim

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#searchCity").bind("click", function(event) {
        $.ajax({async: true, data: {},
            dataType: "JSON", success: function(data, textStatus) {
            }, type: "GET", url: "http:\/\/api.geonames.org\/searchJSON"});
        return false;
    });
});
```

Aparentemente, a função .bind() não funciona no Internet Explorer, e li que posso usar o .on() para substituí-lo.

A questão é: posso trocar esses métodos sem ter que mexer no core do CakePHP ou há alguma solução mais inteligente?

Comment: Qual a versão do seu cakephp?

Comment: já tentou "onclick" ao inves de "click"?

Comment: Acho que descobri o que está acontecendo, e não tem nada a ver com o .bind(). Eu estou tentando fazer uma requisição a uma url externa, e o IE está me bloqueando por causa da Same origin policy. Tem algum jeito de contornar isso??

Comment: Tem sim, por favor, faça outra pergunta, com [Ajax Cross Domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-domain_solution). Somente para manter o site "organizado", escolha uma resposta como a que você acha mais correta.

Answer (score 2):

Observando o código nativo do [cakephp](/questions/tagged/cakephp) acredito que você vá precisar criar seu helper personalizado.

Basicamente você vai copiar todas as dependências do [jshelper](/questions/tagged/jshelper) e fazer uma alteração na linha 183 do arquivo `JqueryEngigeHelper.php` de:

```
return sprintf('%s.bind("%s", %s);', $this->selection, $type, $callback);
```

Para:

```
return sprintf('%s.on("%s", %s);', $this->selection, $type, $callback);
```

Para achar os arquivos que você terá que duplicar acesse a pasta:

```
lib/Cake/View/Helper/JqueryEngineHelper.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Não tem um motivo aparente para não funcionar no IE olha o código interno do bind no jquery

```
bind: function( types, data, fn ) {
    return this.on( types, null, data, fn );
}
```

Agora a chamada do `on`

```
on: function(types, selector, data, fn)
```

Então, como podemos notar o `bind` chama o `on` passando o segundo parâmetro que seria o seletor como `null`, somente isso.

Comment: A resposta não responde a pergunta.

Answer (score -1):

O método [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) é a evolução do [bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/), pode trocar sem medo.

da documentação:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the .bind() method is used for attaching an event handler directly to elements.

Comment: Sei que posso mudar, mas o problema é: Como dizer para o Helper usar o .on() ao invés do .bind()???